# Minimal boost.org includes to use just one sub-library

Tags: c++, boost

I'd like to use the [boost](http://www.boost.org) `smart_ptr` library. I don't want any of the other libraries because I'm trying to keep my project small.

When I added just the `smart_ptr` library I got complaints that the `config.hpp` header couldn't be found. I added that file then my compiler said it couldn't find the `assert.hpp` header. I gave up after that and just included the entire boost library.

Is there a minimal set of boost libraries that must be used if I want to use one of the sub-libraries (e.g., `smart_ptr`)?

The `#include` statement I use is:

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

The directory structure I have looks like this

```
MyProject/
    main.cpp
    MyLib/
         . . . My library code is here. . .
    boost/
        boost/
            smart_ptr/
            smart_ptr.hpp
            . . . All other boost sub-libraries are also here. . .
```

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Please show the associated `#include` line.  And explain your layout of source code files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The utility `bcp` can be used to extract a boost header and its dependencies.

Extracting single libraries can be a bit complicated because the dependency structure is not documented and changes between releases. `bcp` is the way to go.

You can find it [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html).